# Book Series (like 5+ books I think) with tan-ish covers about of group of adolescents

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I would have read them between 2003-2007 I think, the most I can remember is that it was about a group of teens who were either on a specific quest or adventuring and each teen was a different “class” like in DnD almost. The warrior/fighter one got hooked swords from his master that could be used individually or as one big sword.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember? Were these normal teens transported to this DnD-like word, or did they exist in the world from the beginning of the series?